# Creating a stylesheet pseudo-state for a custom QWidget

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have a created a custom widget, let's call it MyWidget. It is derived from QWidget. I want to use [Style Sheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html) to apply a style to MyWidget, using an external QSS file.

I want to change its background colour when I click on it (and return to its original colour when I release the mouse button).

I have investigated two solutions, but so far neither is working.

### With custom pseudo-state?

The style sheet contains something like:

```
MyWidget {
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255,0,0);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

QWidget#MyWidget:pressed {
  background: rgb(0,0,255);
  border-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

Then the question is, what should I write to let QSS know the "pressed" pseudo-state of MyWidget?

### With QObject::setProperty()?

I also tried to use [QObject::setProperty()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#setProperty)

```
MyWidget {
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255,0,0);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

QWidget#MyWidget[pressed="true"] {
  background: rgb(0,0,255);
  border-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

and

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    setProperty("pressed", true);
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    setProperty("pressed", false);
    QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

but it did not change the background colour of MyWidget when I clicked on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Actually my problem was this line `QWidget#MyWidget[pressed="true"]` in the QSS file.

Here is a working solution for me

```
MyWidget {
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255,0,0);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

MyWidget[pressed="true"] {
  background: rgb(0,0,255);
  border-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

Also we need to add [unpolish()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyle.html#unpolish)/[polish()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyle.html#polish) after QWidget::setProperty().

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    setProperty("pressed", true);
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);

    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    setProperty("pressed", false);
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);

    QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

That said, I'm still interested in a solution based on a custom pseudo-state.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement usage of predefined pseudo-states like this (Code in Python, but in C++ must be similar)

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QStyle, QStyleOption
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QMouseEvent, QPaintEvent, QPainter

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None, f: Qt.WindowType = Qt.WindowType.Widget) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent, f)
        self.pressed = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self.pressed = True
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.pressed = False
        self.update()

    def initStyleOption(self, option: QStyleOption) -> None:
        if self.pressed: 
            option.state |= QStyle.StateFlag.State_Sunken

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent) -> None:
        opt= QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        p = QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PrimitiveElement.PE_Widget, opt, p, self)
        super().paintEvent(event)
```

and write in QSS like

```
MyWidget {
    background: green;
}
MyWidget:pressed{
    background: red;
}
```